# How to export data with tab delimiters using Apex Data Loader?

Tags: data-loader

The internet vaguely says that this is possible. I need this feature to export translation values from a custom object and then import this back into Salesforce using translation workbench. Translation workbench accepts:

1. Field delimiter: Tab
2. Character delimiter: None

How can we achieve a tab delimited data export from a custom object using Apex Data Loader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  Jitterbit Dataloader

In the Jitterbit Dataloader , you can create a FileFormat for both Source and Target side. In the FileFormat , you can specify the delimiter to be Comma(,), Pipe(|), Tab(\t) etc as per your requirement.