# Can we export TAB delimited file from Salesforce

Tags: data-loader

I have a requirement to export the tab delimited file from SFDC. Can we do it apex dataloader. I believe, there is no way to do it ? let me know if there is a workaround.

has anyone used some good free tools to convert the CSV into TAB delimited ? Thanks .

Comment: Thanks all .  I have to automate this process  like cliq. I have to extract the file at the end of business day and copy over to Shared file location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your use case allow you to manually open it in Excel and do a Save-As to select .tsv?

I think the standard SFDC DataLoader can only read from CSVs, from command-line mode:  https://na14.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_data_loader.pdf (page 31)

If you're scripting a solution, plenty of VB scripts on Google for Windows or Python scripts for linux.  Alternately, convert one of those to an Apex Class.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of: [How to export data with tab delimiters using Apex Data Loader?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30082/how-to-export-data-with-tab-delimiters-using-apex-data-loader)

Option 1: Jitterbit data loader - create a FileFormat

Option 2: Apex data loader; open CSV file using OpenOffice.org, save as Text CSV, **edit filter settings**, and change field delimiter to <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You can export data to a tab delimited file using a number of tools. Two of which have been mentioned. I prefer Dataloader.io it's free and easy to use and allows for exporting of large data sets quickly as well as importing data sets quickly.